# Fade effect is removed from dynamically added tabs

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to use Bootstrap's togglable tabs (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) with the fade effect. Which works just fine when I create a static HTML file.

However, when dynamically adding tabs via jQuery, the `fade` class is removed from the respective DOM nodes and the tab-panes no longer fade in and out when switching between tabs. I can re-add the `fade` class to the tab-panes using the browser's developer tools ('elements' in Chrome) to make it work as expected again. So it's really not clear to me why the `fade` class gets removed at all. :(

What do I have to do so that the `fade` class is not removed when inserting the tab-pane?

Following fiddle demonstrates the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/zabbarob/44VDD/

The code I use in the fiddle is

```html
<div id="tabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs"></ul>
    <div class="tab-content"></div>
</div>
```

and

```js
function appendTab(title) {
    $('#tabs > .nav').append(
        '<li><a href="#' + title + '" data-toggle="tab">'
        + title + '</a></li>'
    );
    $('#tabs > .tab-content').append(
        '<div class="tab-pane fade in" id="' + title + '">'
        + 'tab pane of ' + title + '</div>'
    );
}
appendTab('First');
appendTab('Second');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your resulting html markup is missing several things to work.

1.) right now you are giving every `div` element the `fade in` class, but just the active one needs it, every other needs just the `fade`class.

2.) you are not declaring an active element in the navigation list

3.) you are not marking the active element as active in the content area

[working example](http://www.bootply.com/117975)

In my example I choose the first element to be the one marked active via a counter. Modify your function (call), so that it suits your needs. The first element that calls your function gets marked as active now.

Comment: great! that not only solved my problem :-) but also made me understand what i did wrong! thanks a lot!